# Javascript in DIVI : mouseenter does not work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mouseenter

I am creating a website for a client using Divi on WordPress.

I need to add some js code to create a `mouseenter` effet in order to change a logo to a Qr code.

There is the code :

```
    window.onload = function(){
        let wechatLogo = document.querySelector('#wechat img');
        wechatLogo.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
            wechatLogo.src = "/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/微信图片_20201017141208-1.jpg";
    });
    }
```

It does nothing on the front and there is not any errors.

I need probably your helps.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is NOT the code you have on your site.

Comment: Could you be specific on which logo? Also have you tried `console.log` in the event listener ? Does that fire?

Comment: the id of the logo img is "wechat". The logo just under "Suivez nous sur". I have add now `console.log` in the eventlistener and it works. I mean it shows the url of img that i want it to appear. But the image does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `wechatLogo.srcset`

```
window.onload = function(){
        let wechatLogo = document.querySelector('#wechat img');
        wechatLogo.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
            wechatLogo.srcset = "https://www.ateliersfrancochinois.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/微信图片_20201017141208-1.jpg";
    });
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's all good for me ! Could you please just explain why we should use `srcset` instead of `src` right here ?.